# Responsive AdSense Units Break Layout On Window Resize: How To Fix?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, responsive-design, adsense

I've created a responsive web layout on two of my sites, and it works beautifully, but I'm struggling to implement Google AdSense responsive ads. The ads work great on mobile, reloading on orientation changes, but on desktops, they break the layout whenever the browser window is resized. In some cases, they spill over, blocking content, which is a violation of AdSense policy.

I would ideally like to be able to signal the ads to reload, but I don't know if this is possible in a way that is allowed under google's policies.

As a next-best solution, I wrote javascript that hides the ads if the window is resized past a breakpoint, but the Google team informed me that this solution was in violation of their policies. Because it's only a small portion of users that resize windows at any given time, the lost revenue from ads is not a big deal to me--whereas the broken layout, which looks unprofessional and makes a bad impression--is a big deal to me.

Do you know of any way to handle this situation gracefully, in line with Google's policies? Have any of you successfully implemented responsive AdSense units in a way that solved this problem?

Comment: I've found that colspan messes up adsense resizing as well.  It works fine on page load but not if you resize the window.